# Select div using jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an event listener on dynamically created elements:

```
<script>
        $(document).on('change', '.inputfile', function() {
            var name = ($(this).val().split('\\').pop());
            selectFile(name);
        });
</script>
```

Once file is selected, i would like to append a paragraph showing the filename itself. My problem is that jquery selector is not working:

```
function selectFile(filename) {
        alert(filename);
        var classes = $(this).closest('.inputgroup');
        $('classes').append('<p>'+filename+'</p>');
}
```

I would like to append the paragraph in the nearest div with class=inputgroup, because there are several div with that class.
Using a simple `$('.inputgroup').append('<p>'+filename+'</p>');` is ok and paragraph is created.
This is the HTML:

```
<div class="inputgroup">
   <label class="btn btn-default btn-info" style="margin-top: 8px">
         Browse <input type="file" style="display: none;" class="inputfile"/>
   </label>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="myAjax()">Ok</button>
   <span id="remove_field" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: middle"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe that `$(this).closest('.inputgroup');` is out of scope and shouldn't work, $('this) at that point is the document.

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL even if i put that in the event handler (inside the HTML file) there is no effect

Comment: the jQuery `$(this)` is the instance, the DOM element, that generate the event, BUT it points to this element only within the function that the event runs... so `$(document).on('change', '.inputfile', function() { ... }` is the scope you want to have for `$(this).closest('.inputgroup');` because in it `$(this)` is the element with `id=".inputfile"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line

```
$('classes').append('<p>'+filename+'</p>');
```

Is searching for an element named "classes" - that's not a valid HTML element.

I think you wanted

```
$(this).closest('.inputgroup').append('<p>'+filename+'</p>');
```

Based on this line of your question

> I would like to append the paragraph in the nearest div with class=inputgroup

But you should put this straight in the event handler, otherwise `this` has a different meaning

```
$(document).on('change', '.inputfile', function() {
    var name = ($(this).val().split('\\').pop());
    $(this).closest('.inputgroup').append('<p>'+name+'</p>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code

`var classes = $(this).closest('.inputgroup');
$('classes').append('<p>'+filename+'</p>');`

The first line gives you an jQuery object. Which you can directly use to append the `p` tag.

As already mentioned in other answer your second line looks for a element named `classes` which does not exist.

So simply use the Jquery object you have and append the paragraph. Like below

`classes.append('<p>'+filename+'</p>');`